# Paypal recurring payments redirects to paypal's homepage

Tags: node.js, redirect, paypal, payment, recurring

I'm trying to use Paypal's recurring payments, my code works well on the sandbox but when I move to production I seem to have trouble.

In production, Paypal's response include the token as expected and I redirect the user to the checkout page, at that point, instead of getting the Paypal's checkout page, Paypal redirects the user again to the Paypal's business home page. No error messages, no notifications, nothing. It just redirects the user.

My guess is I may need to enable something in my Paypal's account (which is a business account, by the way) but I don't seem to be able to figure out what's going on. Any idea?

**SOLVED**: There was a typo in the checkout URL, and it seems like Paypal was redirecting to the home page instead of showing a 404 page.

Comment: Is there anyway to see it on website?

Comment: What product are you using? Express Checkout? Is this for a PayPal Payment or a CC payment?

Comment: **solved**: there was a typo in the checkout URL, my mistake. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Fakito, can you answer + accept your own answer in the box bello.Add some more details in case someone in the future has the same problem? Otherwise this question will probably get closed

Comment: @fmsf I can't accept my own answer, it says I must wait 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: There was a typo in the checkout URL, and it seems like Paypal was redirecting to the home page instead of showing a 404 page.

Comment: Hi please can you explain a bit more I have the same problem.Using easy digital downloads and a buisness paypal account but it worked for one week and now its redirecting users to paypal homepage whats the trick to fix it? Thankyou